# Are there any events dispatched after a user's email confirmation in joomla 3.x?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, emails, registration, plugin-events

I need to perform some actions after the user confirms their email accounts/registration. I have been looking for whether Joomla dispatches any events on registration confirmation but i still cant find any. It would be an honor if you guys could help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activation itself does not have any events it triggers.

It may be worth looking into the [onUserBeforeSave](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserBeforeSave) event. This is called everytime a change it made to the user. So it should do the trick.

So check the parameters to see if there is anything you can use to determine if this is an activation.

Hope this helps.